# probability confusion

Tags: probability

There are ten balls in a bag numbered  **1 to 10**

I have to pick a number from **1 to 10**

I put my hand in the bag and **pick one ball** , if it matches my number I win

if it doesn't I lose

**After each game the ball is replaced**

My question is - If I play this game **10 times** what is the probability I win **exactly** five times ?

Not sure how to tackle this question can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: Do you know about binomial random variables?  Also, I wouldn't recommend the game-theory tag.

Comment: 1. What is the probability of win for the first pick? 2. Does the probability of some pick depends on having won or lost the previous ?

Comment: 10% chance to win each time

Comment: each game is independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Michael stated, you have a binomial random variable. Let n be the number of trials (10 in your case), X be the number of successes (number of times you win) and p be the probability of success in each case (0.1 in your case). Then,

$P(X=x) = {n \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$

where ${n \choose x}=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$

Sub your values for n, x, and p into that equation and you'll have the probability you want. Essentially you're multiplying the probability of winning 5 times ($p^x$) by the probability of not winning 5 times ($(1-p)^{n-x}$), and multiplying that by all the different combinations of ways that can occur (${n \choose x}$).

Hope that helps!

Comment: so the number of combinations is 10*9*8*7*6  divided by 5! = 252

Comment: and I multiply by .10 five times and by .9 five times?

Comment: Both of those look correct to me